# Facebook Connect Wall Posting comes as popup only. How to change that?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have facebook app for my website and the facebook connect works fine. I have the post on the user's wall option but posting on the wall happens as a popup and most browsers are automatically disabling the popup. So wall post is not working as i want it to as most people dont enable popups. Is there any solution to make this posting as not a popup.

The code that i have used for fb connect is

```
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId  : '',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true , // parse XFBML
        oauth : true // Enable oauth authentication
    });

FB.login(function(response)
{
    if (response.authResponse)
    {

        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',
                {
                    message     : "",
                    link        : '',
                    picture     : "",
                    name        : '',
                   description  : ''

           },
           function(response) {
               showLoader(false);

                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
    }

}, { scope : 'publish_stream' });
};

</script>

<!-- FACEBOOK -->        
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function() {
 var e = document.createElement('script');
// replacing with an older version until FB fixes the cancel-login bug
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  //e.src = 'scripts/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<!-- END-OF-FACEBOOK -->
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s not the posting that opens the popup (`FB.api` is a background method, it does never open a popup) – but the `FB.login` call.

As mentioned in the docs, this method should not be called on page load, but on explicit user interaction (f.e. click on a login button) instead. Popup blockers in current browsers in their default configuration do not block popups that occur on user interaction.

If that’s not good enough for you, then you can use the direct URL version of the login dialog, that will lead the user to Facebook and back to your page after login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/#step2